# which side requests for images in an SSR website page?

Tags: node.js, backend, server-side-rendering

For example, I have an SSR website and a user sends a request to the server for a page(e.g xxx.com). This page contains some static assets.

Will the server load all these assets and sent a completed HTML page to users? just the simplest scenario (`<img src='/a.png' />`) without any tricky methods such as lazyloading.

Or it is the client who sends GET requests such as xxx.com/a.png, xxx.com/b.jepg later to fetch these static assets?